# ASP.NET RegisterClientScriptBlock, RegsiterStartupScript issues

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on a set of ASP.NET applications using a master page.
When I try to register a clientscript - an alert box for instance, in the Page_Load it works fine. However if I try to do the same from any method or event handler of the same class it doesn't.
Also, it doesn't seem to matter which Register method you use, both work only in the Page_Load (for me).

I could not find another way so far to alert the user about exceptions and such from within the code (other than building a user control) and I figure in a similar situation other JavaScript codes won't execute either...for example one that would refresh an iframe content.

I'm wondering if there is a best practice to achieve a little more dinamic interaction between JavaScript and code behind?

What I mean is something that:

- can be called from anywhere in the codebehind
- UpdatePanels and MasterPages don't make it unreliable

Comment: When you call those two methods, which class are they from?  Page, ClientScript or ScriptManager?

And is there any AJAX involved with these pages?

Comment: Yes, UpdatePanels, MasterPages involve AJAX and the mentioned EventHandlers are part of the Page class...

Comment: I think your problem is two fold. 1. You are trying to call Javascript during an asynchronous postback; but the Page's version of the RegisterClientScriptBlock method only works on synchronous postbacks.  2. It seems like you are looking for 1 place to catch ALL server side errors (similar to how Facebook handles error).  You could try override the Page's OnError method.
See: http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is probably not an universal standard, but I find it very easy to handle errors like this:

First of all you need to declare a `ScriptManager` in your master page.

In the master page's code behind I declare my error handling functions like this:

```
public void ShowError(string message){
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, typeof(Page), "showError", String.Format("ShowError({0});", message), true);
}
```

I usually create an interface with all the possible "overrides" for the `ShowError` method. For example, you might want to handle parameters in a different way, like a custom `Exception` or maybe just different types of messages(information, warnings, errors)

You can then use this interface by declaring it as a global variable in your page/user control:

```
#region Globals
    IMaster _master;
```

Ok, the next step would be to declare this master page in our page/user control file. I usually do it in the page load event like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    _master = Page.Master as IMaster;
}
```

In this case `IMaster` is the interface that I created before.

And there you go, now you can use the methods you defined in your master page like this:

```
public void MyMethod(){
    try
    {
        //do something
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _master.ShowError(ex);
    }
}
```

This way you have a standardized and clean way to handle errors in your application.

Hope this helps :)